# How can I calculate a formula in Excel VBA and put its value in a variable? For example I want to set x equal to COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)

Tags: excel, vba

How can I calculate a formula in Excel VBA and put its value in a variable?
For example I want to set x equal to COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)

When I write `x=WorksheetFunction.COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)` I get the error

> "Expected: list separator or )"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing the range reference to the worksheet function properly. You need to use a VBA style reference not a worksheet style reference.

```
'VBA style using worksheet codename
x = WorksheetFunction.COUNTA(Sheet1.Range("A:A"))

'VBA style using worksheet name
 x = WorksheetFunction.COUNTA(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The function needs a `Range`, so:

```
Sub kount()
    Dim r As Range, x As Long

    Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        x = .CountA(r)
    End With
End Sub
```